# Replace underscores with spaces for all files in directory

Tags: bash, rename

For all files in a directory, I want to replace the underscores in the filename with spaces.

I tried this solution, which does the opposite of what I want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806868/linux-replacing-spaces-in-the-file-names

But switched the space with the underscore. That does not work, giving the error

```
´x´ is not a directory
```

Where x is the last word in the filename, for example `hello_world_x`

What is the correct command to replace underscores with spaces for all files in a directory?

Comment: It is a terrible ideia to have spaces in filenames, I would prefer a lot _, even for scripting.

Comment: I deleted the comments but he really did have a point. Please don't do this. File names with spaces are a very bad idea and will make anything you need to do down the line more complex for no reason. I strongly urge you to reconsider and avoid using spaces.

Comment: And, this should still be linked here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943  (@terdon: Thanks for the good moderation. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After you cd to the correct directory, this script will reliably solve your need (not portable because of the `${var//pat/str}` expansion):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -- *_*
for file; do
    mv -- "$file" "${file//_/ }"
done
```

`*_*` The glob `*_*` will select all files that have an `_` in their names.

`set --` Those names (even including spaces or new-lines) will be reliably set to the positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, etc. with the simple command `set -- "list"`

`for file;` Then, each positional parameter will be (in turn) assigned to the var file.

`do ... done` contains the commands to execute (for each `$file`).

`mv -- "$file" "${file//_/ }"` will move (rename) each file to the same name with each (all) `_` replaced by   (space).

**Note**: You may add the `-i` (interactive) option to avoid overwriting already existing files. If the file exist, `mv` will ask. With a caveat: there needs to be an interactive shell where `mv` could communicate with the user.

```
mv -i -- "$file" "${file//_/ }"
```

Comment: @Wildcard Probably a better answer now. Changed to `-i`.

Comment: Great answer; I'd never used the `bash` variable substitution feature.  One note about `mv`: when the target name exists already as a *directory*, `mv` will simply put the file *in* that directory without renaming either the file or the directory.  Neither `-i` nor `-n` will prevent this behavior; you would have to check for the existence of the target first.  (For the question asked about, this is an *extreme* edge case and more trouble than it's worth to check for, but for production environments it's good to be aware of.)  If this is unclear: `touch file1; mkdir file2; mv -i -n file1 file2`

Comment: Yes @Wildcard the file will be moved, but, as no file was erased, no harm done. Having a directory with the (almost) same name of a file is just calling for trouble.

Answer (score 12):

Plagiarizing the code from the answer you linked to and making it more
robust:

```
for file in *; do mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | tr '_' ' ')" ; done
```

Quoting ensures that each file name is passed to `mv` as a single
token, rather than it being broken at space boundaries.

If you have access to the Perl-based rename utility, the following
will work as well:

```
rename -n 's/_/ /g' *
```

(Remove the `-n` switch after confirming that the preview corresponds
to what you would like to do.)

Comment: This will execute a move (`mv`) for **all** files whether they have `_` or not. Calling an external utility (tr) for something bash could do on its own is also not such a nice idea.

Comment: @BinaryZebra: Agreed. I made no effort to pass judgment on whether the request or referenced code are sane.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -depth -name "*_*" -exec \
    sh -cf '
        for f do   IFS=_
            IFS=\  set "${f%/*}/"${f##*/}$0
            mv "$f" "$*"
        done
    ' _ {} +
```

a POSIX `sh` will expand away the changes as configured with its *Internal Field Separator*.